# Why do I get a Type Error when calling a valid function? | Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Every time I call this function I receive an error telling me that "TypeError: co.newMethod2 is not a function"

I don't understand why as my method is valid in my type script file. Here is my code

**create-sharecase.component.html**

```
<div> 
    <p> Template Description </p>
     <textarea [ngModel]="textValue" (ngModelChange)="newMethod2()">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

**create-sharecase.component.ts**

```
newMethod2(){
    console.log("Text Area Method");
if (this.textValue != '') {
    console.log("Text Value" + this.textValue);
}}`
```

To me this should be valid code and should execute! All hep will be appreciated!

Comment: could you add your @Component data?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) for Angular.

Comment: Component decorator is already in place for the type script file

Comment: @WilliamHampshire Here is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/tpOc18AfoJcwwRk4Nfym

Comment: Should work fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/2qdOy6cTNSuroGoXobNn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It seems the way you wrote your method is wrong, here's what I propose :

```
this.newMethod2 = () => {
    console.log("Test Area  Method");
    if (this.textValue != ''){
        console.log("Other text");
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

USe ngchange event for call a function when change any artibutes or change angular function ... try this

```
**strong text**
<div> 
    <p> Template Description </p>
     <textarea ngModel="textValue" ngChange="newMethod2()"></textarea>
</div>
```

and angular ..

```
function newMethod2 ()  {
    console.log("Test Area  Method");
    if (this.textValue != ''){
        console.log("Other text");
    }
};
```